# How to extract file to particular type using winzip

Tags: zip, winzip

If I have a file, how do I extract the file so that it is of a particular type(.xlsx file). In WinZip, all I see is Extract To option.

Answer (score 2):

Extract to: is where you want to extract the zip file to.  The file will be extracted as the file type that it is saved in.  To convert to XLSX, open the file with excel or open office, and then save as .xlsx
Let me know if this resolves your issue. 
Thanks,
Matt

Comment: BTW, XLSX, DOCX and other Office -X format files are themselves compressed archives, so you can open those types of files with 7-Zip and probably with WinZip. Not sure if that clarifies anything ;-)

Comment: The file is very large. If I open in excel it says "cannot load file completely". My question is, after this message, I save the file as an xlsx file, will all the rows be in the file?